# Xcode is not building my application because of Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph

Tags: xcode, pbx

I have no idea what this error is about. It is refusing to compile. It is a giant project with over 150 source files and with about 20 3rd party dependencies.

> Internal error occurred while creating
> dependency graph:
> -[PBXTargetBuildContext ]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

It worked perfectly fine previously. Now **Xcode** is breaking in the last second.

And yes, I have rebooted my Mac. I am running Xcode 3.2.2 but I don't think that matters as I haven't updated anything else because I always cancel those irritating update pop-ups. I wish there would be a mode which would disable all pop-up windows.

Comment: Hide your Dock. You won't see the red star with the '1' anymore and your frustration is gone :)

Comment: +1 for descriptive title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=290034 :

> My Works very nice but when I change
>   my TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY from iphone
>   to ipad I got this erros: Internal
>   error occurred while creating
>   dependency graph:
>   -[PBXTargetBuildContext ]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x200f16140
>
> Any one know why ? I cannot buld a
>   iPad App ? Thanks

Try changing `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` to iPhone, if it is iPad. Maybe that will work.

---

Also, try building it from the command line:

```
$ xcodebuild -project someawesomeproj -alltargets
```

---

If that also sucks, try creating a brand new Xcode project, import all resources, files and source code and recreate all targets, etc...

Comment: If that also sucks, try creating a brand new Xcode project - heh, it would take me a week O.o